# How to configure two scheme authentication in AspNetCore 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core-2.0, bearer-token

appsettings:

[image]

Startup.cs:

[image]

Controller:

[image]

I add as settings but keep getting authorization error, helmp me ?

Comment: what's your error message?

Comment: Please paste your code as text. Images are harder to search for and therefore answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Startup.cs in ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services):

```
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Bearer";
})
.AddOAuthIntrospection("Bearer", o =>
{
    o.Authority = new Uri(Configuration["URL"]);
    o.Audiences.Add("Audiences");
    o.ClientId = Configuration["OpenIdConnectOptions:ClientId"];
    o.ClientSecret = Configuration["OpenIdConnectOptions:ClientSecret"];
}).AddOAuthIntrospection("Bearer2", o =>
{
    o.Authority = new Uri(Configuration["URL"]);
    o.Audiences.Add("Audiences");
    o.ClientId = Configuration["OpenIdConnectOptions:ClientId2"];
    o.ClientSecret = Configuration["OpenIdConnectOptions:ClientSecret2"];
});
```

All on Controller:

```
[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer,Bearer2")]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class Controller : ControllerBase
{
```